# PHP preg_replace needs improvement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Ok, I have a string as follows:

```
$disallowedBBC = 'abbr|acronym|anchor|bdo|black|blue|br|color|email|flash|font|ftp|glow|green|html|hr|img|iurl|li|list|ltr|url|quote';
```

And than a `preg_replace` on the actual string (`$message` variable) that should get rid of all bbc code that is not allowed according to the `$disallowedBBC` variable:

```
$message = preg_replace("/\[($disallowedBBC)[^]]*](.*?)\[\/($disallowedBBC)\]/is", "$2", $message);
```

But, for some reason, the `[hr]` tag is getting past this preg_replace.  So, in this case:

```
$message = '[hr]Test';
```

It outputs the `[hr]` tag, but should remove it.  What is wrong with my regex?

Basically...

How to change it so that it removes all [hr] and/or [hr]Test[/hr] altogether? But would also need to get rid of instances where [url=http://someurl.com]Some Url[/url].  And it should remove `[color=red]` from a string as follows: `[color=red]Testing`

For example, it needs to get rid of `[{tag}]` and if it has a closing tag `[/{tag}]`, but if there is no closing tag, it needs to get rid of the opening tag, and vice versa.  It should be able to capture anything within the {tag} that is within the brackets as well, such as:  `[quote author=Solomon time=7834783470]Just a quote here[/quote] Additional text here...`

So, this should output:  `Just a quote here Additional text here...`

Comment: Your regex matches `[hr]Test[/hr]` but not `[hr]Test`

Comment: That does not change anything, still doesn't get rid of the [hr] tag.

Comment: How to change it so that it removes all `[hr]` and/or `[hr]Test[/hr]` altogether?  But would also need to get rid of instances where `[url=http://someurl.com]Some Url[/url]`

Comment: So basically, it would need to get rid of `[color=red]` from the string `[color=red]Testing` also.

Comment: @xdazz - How would I be able to match either of these??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two preg_replaces.  One to first get rid of the pairs of [hr]...[/hr] and then a second to get rid of any remaining [hr]...

```
$message = preg_replace("/\[($disallowedBBC)[^\]]*](.*?)\[\/($disallowedBBC)\]/is", "$2", $message);
$message = preg_replace("/\[($disallowedBBC)[^\]]*]/is", "", $message);
```

I you try to do it in one step, then things like "abc[br]blahblah[hr]gak[/hr]def" will become "abcdef".  You might be able to do it if you can place restrictions on the blahblah portion.

You can, of course, combine these into one preg_replace call by using the array syntax (but remember that the order matters):

```
$patterns = array("/\[($disallowedBBC)[^\]]*](.*?)\[\/($disallowedBBC)\]/is",
                  "/\[($disallowedBBC)[^\]]*]/is", );
$replacements = array("$2", "");
$message = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $message);
```

Comment: Your example takes:  `[hr]Test` and output `hrTest`, but is should only output:  `Test`  FYI: I updated my question at the end.  And also, thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: I see why.  I changed the 2nd replacement string (I wasn't thinking).